# Rest is your decision Or decision rests with you?

Tags: word-choice

On responding to a question to choose one option and after  you choose, you say:

> Rest is your decision.

Or

> Decision rests with you.

What should be used instead of above two sentences if both are wrong?

Comment: _The decision rests with you_ is asking the _other_ person to choose, not what you say after you have made a choice!

Answer (score 7):

> The rest is your decision.

means that something (or the main part of it) has been already decided (likely, by others) and now it's up to you to settle the rest ([what left or remaining; remainder](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/rest) (1))

> The decision rests with you.

means that [you have authority or responsibility, or you are the one who will make that decision](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/rest) (4).